# Checking for validation error and feching the error in a Blade template when having an associative array of inputs

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-blade

I'm struggling to check for validation errors and then fetch the errors in a Blade template when I'm having an array of inputs. I've simplified the HTML and PHP code for demonstration purposes.

The HTML code:

```
<form>
    <p>Title</p>
    Female: <input type="text" name="title[female]">
    Male: <input type="text" name="title[male]">

    <p>Female Answers</p>
    <input type="text" name="answer[female][]">
    <input type="text" name="answer[female][]">
    <input type="text" name="answer[female][]">

    <p>Male Answers</p>
    <input type="text" name="answer[male][]">
    <input type="text" name="answer[male][]">
    <input type="text" name="answer[male][]">
</form>
```

The validation rules are defined as following:

```
$rules = [
    'title.*' => 'required|min:10|max:255',
    'answer.females.*' => 'required',
    'answer.males.*' => 'required'
];
```

The problem is that when I trying to reach for this errors in the template I get an error like:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [...]

I tried multiple approaches for checking for the errors but none of them worked:

```
{{ $errors->has('title.' . $gender) ? 'form-error' : '' }}
{{ $errors->has('title')[$gender] ? 'form-error' : '' }}
{{ $errors->has('title.{$gender}') ? 'form-error' : '' }}

// Where $gender contains the gender as string, like "females", "males".
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this format

```
{!! $errors->first('title.'. $gender , 'form-error') !!}
```